# Differential equation of second order (non-linear)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Is there a proper way of solving this differential equation of the second order?
$$
\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=ay^2
$$
Is it even possible?

Comment: [Mathematica](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27%27%28x%29+%3D+a+y%28x%29%5E2) gives :$$y(x) = \left(\dfrac{6}{a}\right)^{3/2}\wp\left[ \left(\dfrac{a}{6}\right)^{3/2}\ (x+c_1);  0, c_2\right]$$

Comment: You shouldn't post the same question twice. Instead, just edit the original.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(I'm going to set $y'=dy/dx$ and so on for brevity.) Multiply both sides by $2y'$:
$$ 2y'y'' = 2ay'y^2. $$
Because
$$ (y'^2)' = 2y'y'', $$
we can integrate the equation once to get
$$ y'^2 = \frac{2a}{3}(y^3+A), $$
$A$ an arbitrary constant. Rearranging this and taking the square root,
$$ \sqrt{2a/3}(x+B) = \pm \int \frac{dy}{\sqrt{ y^3+A }} $$
Except in special cases ($A=0$ being the only one, I suspect), the integral on the right cannot be solved in terms of elementary functions: a solution to this sort of integral equation (or the previous differential equation) is called an [elliptic function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EllipticFunction.html) (note the equations at the bottom of the page), because such things originate in finding the inverse function of the arc length of an ellipse.

Comment: according to the result of mathematica, it should be possible to say something for the integral you found.